# HDD SMART Recovery

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, smart, windows-backup, bad-sectors

I am performing data recovery on a HDD that has SMART failure. I need to get all the data copied off this disk. The disk contains a Windows C partition, that is all. I have many softwares and external disks for this task, the quantity of tools is not the issue, I have Hirens, Aomei, RecoverIt full edition, Linux, and others. There is 500Gb of data on this 1Tb disk, and anytime I attempt to copy the files individually, it copies 98% and reports that 2% cannot be read; I tell Windows to always automatically skip files and areas that cannot be read, but none-the-less, it still gets stuck moving 0bytes of data for long periods of time, and moving even a few Gb can sometimes take hours. I used Aomei Backupper to clone the disk, but it failed due to inability to read parts of the disk. What is the most time and labor efficient method to copy the data? I cannot monitor this disk transfer for 40 straight hours, I do not have the time for that. I cannot afford to pay professional data recovery specialists to recovery this. Thanks dudes.

Comment: "What is the most time and labor efficient method to copy the data?" - You have likely exceeded your ability to perform the data recovery on the device.  If the data is critical professional data recovery services have additional software and tools that might allow them to be successful.  They typically charge a fee to look at the device, but only charge the more expensive feed, if they are able to recover the data off the device.

Comment: I don't agree to this opinion - see the answer of cybernard.

Answer (score 1):

From a linux bootable USB thumb drive or whatever.

try ddrescue

```
 ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sda /dev/sdb mapfile
```

This copies the 1st hard drive (sda) to the second hard drive (sdb).
**The existing contents of the 2nd hard drive will be erased.**

This may take a long time, but it won't require you to baby sit it.

Comment: 1) Will this command skip bad sectors?          2) What is a different command to clone a specific partition to an empty disk, while skipping bad sectors?

Comment: It would not allow me to edit this. Here is my edit of the above:    Thank you, I was aware of dd, but not ddrescue which skips bad sectors, I may try that. What is a different command to clone a specific partition to an empty disk, while skipping bad sectors? Thank you again for posting this answer cybernard, your info was not in the other Question Page for this bad sector issue. I will follow your advice...

Comment: Nothing can 100% skip bad sectors you can change **-r 3** to **-r 1** so it gives up after 1 try.  The issue is, it has to detect the sector is bad in the first place, so it has to attempt to read it at least once.  So you need to pre-create an empty partition on the destination.  Then linux use partition numbers, so sda would become sda2 (or etc) and sdb would become sdb2 ( or etc)  **lsblk** should help you identify the correct partition number.